# Learn current time and current frame from a playing video with python

Tags: python, video, time, frame

I want to play a video with python.

When video is playing i want to get current time of video and current frame as a picture.

How can i do this ?

Comment: So we should write code for you? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Arman, I have a video file and i use cv2 videocapture. Than i can get frame that on specific time as msec.  But this not help me... If i use a timer can i do this ? Ger time from timer and capture frame from vide with it.

Comment: Please post your tried code here , so we can help you better with that

Comment: import cv2

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('d:/video/keep/Le Sang Des Betes.mp4')
vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,20000)
success,image = vidcap.read()
if success:
    cv2.imwrite("frame20sec.jpg", image)
    cv2.imshow("20sec",image)
    cv2.waitKey()  
This is my code. This is working but time specified by me as 20000 msec. I want to get frame at current time